# How can I display Wordpress posts in a repeatable random order?

Tags: wordpress

I would like to control the MySQL statement that Wordpress uses to give me a group of posts. Specifically, I would like to add this to the sql:

```
ORDER BY RAND(CURDATE())
```

This particular implementation has a fixed number of posts that will not be changing. However that would be boring for returning visitors and some posts that are down the page would likely never be seen. I would like to display the posts in a random order that is the same all day and then gets randomized differently the next day.

WP_Query allows for a rand function but it effectively does:

```
ORDER BY RAND()
```

The problem this causes me is that it randomizes differently each time it is queried. I want it to stay the same for every query all day. Seeding the randomizer with today's date accomplishes this. WP_Query however does not allow for seeding the randomizer. So how do I accomplish my desired end?

Comment: You **can** use a seed for determining the random order, q.v. [this great post](http://www.hughlashbrooke.com/2013/08/wordpress-random-post-order-with-correct-pagination/) which discusses how to solve your problem.

Comment: Convert the current date to seconds since epoch, and use that as the random seed in your PHP code.